# My JavaScript doesn't work with my view asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

i'm having some small issues with my JavaScript in my razor view.
I want a user to report absent, but when he picks the time I want a date-time picket to show up so the user doesn't have to manually enter the date.

I also want it to be two different tabs, first tab is where the user will report his vacation and the other tab he will see the reports of older vacations. But now it all appear at ones. I would like to have it similar to this:
[image]

But now "Begärd semstrar" is just sitting under "Begär semester"

This is my view a long with my javascript

```
@using Salesweb.Common.Utilities
@model List<Salesweb.Common.Vacation>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Semester";
}

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('#fromDate').datepicker({
                showButtonPanel: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                firstDay: 1,
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    $('#EndDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(dateText));
                }
            });

            $('#toDate').datepicker({
                showButtonPanel: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                firstDay: 1,
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    $('#EndDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(dateText));
                }
            });

        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="tabs">
                        <div class="portlet light">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#tabs-new">Begär semester</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tabs-list">Begärda semestrar</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <div id="tabs-new">
                                @if (ViewData["posted"] == null)
                                {
                                    using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Vacation", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                                    {
                                        <div class="portlet light">
                                            <div class="portlet-title">
                                                <div class="caption">
                                                    <span class="caption-subject font-green-sharp bold uppercase">Semester</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="portlet-body">
                                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Från:</td>
                                                        <td><input type="text" id="fromDate" name="fromDate" style="width: 70px" /></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Till:</td>
                                                        <td><input type="text" id="toDate" name="toDate" style="width: 70px" /></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Kommentar:</td>
                                                        <td><textarea id="comment" name="comment" style="width: 300px; height: 70px;" rows="5" cols="5"></textarea></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td><input type="submit" value="Begär semester" id="submit" name="submit" /></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <h2 style="color: Green"> Semestern begärd.</h2>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Begär ny semester", "Index")
                                }
                            </div>

                            <div id="tabs-list">
                                <div class="portlet light">
                                    <div class="portlet-title">
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <span class="caption-subject font-green-sharp bold uppercase">Semester</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="portlet-body">
                                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Från</th>
                                                    <th>Till</th>
                                                    <th>Rapportera tid</th>
                                                    <th>Status</th>
                                                    <th>Kommentar</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            @foreach (var vacation in Model)
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>@(vacation.StartDate.ToShortDateString())</td>
                                                    <td>@(vacation.EndDate.ToShortDateString())</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        @if (vacation.TimeReported)
                                                        {
                                                            <a>Tid har rapporterats</a>
                                                        }
                                                        else if (vacation.Status == (int)VacationStatus.Godkänd && !vacation.TimeReported)
                                                        {
                                                            <a href="@(Url.Action("Absent", "Reports", new { vacationId = vacation.VacationID }))">Rapportera tid</a>
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            <a>-</a>
                                                        }
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>@(((VacationStatus)vacation.Status).ToString()) </td>
                                                    <td>@vacation.Comment</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I load in my scripts in a bundle

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3",
                    "~/content/global/plugins/jquery.min.js",
                    "~/content/global/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js",
                    "~/content/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                    "~/content/global/plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
                    "~/content/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js",
                    "~/content/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.js",
                    "~/content/global/scripts/metronic.js",
                    "~/content/admin/layout3/scripts/layout.js",
                    "~/content/admin/layout3/scripts/demo.js",
                    "~/content/admin/pages/scripts/table-advanced.js"
                    ));
```

And than from my _Layout.cshtml I load in the scripts like this.

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

Comment: you have document ready nested. Try removing one. E.g. `$(function () { `not `$(function () {$(function () {`

Comment: @Valamas - AUS: Nested DOM ready handlers are only a *waste of space*. They have no impact if nested.

Comment: Are you getting any (JavaScript) error in console?

Comment: Q: Have you actually included jQuery and jQuery UI in your master/layout page? Can you show the output HTML of the full page *as saved from your browser* too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript doesn't execute in view after a controller redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162942/javascript-doesnt-execute-in-view-after-a-controller-redirect)

Comment: I do get 4 errors, but they are not related to this. They are related to my table from another view http://puu.sh/j8rwm/dc24054fe3.png

Comment: @Jaffer Wilson: That does not appear to be a duplicate as they do not appear to be using jQuery mobile for page loading. How did you jump to that conclusion from the code/tags shown?

Comment: Yes, I am. 
I load my scripts in a bundle http://puu.sh/j8rYa/41dda082ab.png which I than from my _Layout loads in like this:      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Updated my question with your questions.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you are able to simply get the entire page's output HTML *from the browser* then a mockup can be made (e.g. in a JSFiddle). Note: however you are including multiple local scripts and any uncaught error in any preceding JS file will cause it to stop running JavaScript on the page.

Comment: Right, so my error in my javascript might / will stop my script to execute?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Alright, I fixed my other errors and now when I check my source in chrome I get.
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined which I assume happends when you do not load in jQuery. But in my Bundle I load in Jquery-ui after I load in JQuery.

Comment: Use the `Network` tab in the Chrome F12 tools and see if your scripts are all being loaded successfully.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yes, they all get loaded correctly. Even Jquery and JQuery-ui but I do still get the ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined http://puu.sh/j8yF2/9ab74c87c2.png

Comment: Start commenting out scripts from the page until you just have jQuery and a simple alert() inside a DOM ready handler. If that works start adding back scripts until it breaks. If it does not work with jQuery alone, let us know.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I can remove every script except jquery and jquery-ui and I still end up with the ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
And but still in my bundle I load jquery before jquery-ui
http://puu.sh/j8zfP/a0272590ad.png

Comment: Stop any bundle caching by using `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;` inside of the `RegisterBundles` method in `BundleConfig.cs`. You may not be seeing the real situation as previous scripts will still be loading. I should have mentioned this before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83977/discussion-between-trueblueaussie-and-user2902364).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery document ready functions are a little messy / nested

```
$(function () {
    $('#fromDate').datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        firstDay: 1,
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
            $('#EndDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(dateText));
        }
    });

    $('#toDate').datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        firstDay: 1,
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
            $('#EndDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(dateText));
        }
    });
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

I have removed the duplicated document ready checks. Try the code I have provided above.

Comment: Negative, sadly it did not change anything.

Comment: Additional DOM ready handlers have no effect (other than bloating code) as they fire immediately "yes I am ready *already*" :)